# Does ReactTestingLibrary take up a lot of CPU/RAM, causing tests to timeout & fail?

Tags: react-testing-library, circleci

I've had some issues with tests timing out randomly.  Usually on CircleCI, but sometimes locally.  Based on Kent Dodds suggestion to [write fewer longer tests](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/write-fewer-longer-tests) I now have more tests with multiple clicks & multiple network requests (mocking fetch too).  Theses tests seem to timeout.  Just recently CircleCI added a `Resources` tab to the pipeline for some interesting metrics.  When the tests timeout, the 4GB ram clearly gets to 100% for extended time, and the test fails.  On a passed test, the ram stays mostly below 100%.

Failed test (4GB):
[image: Failed Test]

Passed test (4GB):
[image: Passed]

Updated Resource_class to 8GB
[image: passed with 8gb]

I tried a single experiment to update my circleci config so that the `resource_class` gets updated to large/8GB.  Test passed and even better CPU usage %.

So, does React Testing Library take up a lot of horsepower?

Is our default 4GB RAM docker image ok?

Comment: I have the same issue when running on a pipeline. Tests timeout and never finish. And I have only 180 tests. Did you find any solution?